# Hovering over a tag no longer shows the tag popup on the edit/ask a question page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tooltips

I'm trying to suggest an edit to a question and I wanted to verify the tags were correct, but hovering over the tag while on the edit page (note that since it's a suggested edit, it's not the inline editor) doesn't bring up the popup with the excerpt.  Likewise, when writing this question, I can't see the excerpt popup for tags I have already selected.

When I view a question normally, the tag popups work fine, only the edit and "ask a question" pages don't show them.  I have to click on the tag to edit it and use the suggested tag list to see the excerpts.

I see this issue on Windows 7x64: Chrome 13, IE 8, and Firefox 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is intentional.

The old tag editor showed a preview of the entered tags below the text box, and those tags where full blown tags that linked somewhere, showed the popup, etc. We added that as a work-around to at least have the tag description *somewhere*.

It caused some issues though and tended to be confusing, and when the new tag editor had the descriptions built in, we could finally drop it.

Also imagine you want to click a tag to edit it, and suddenly the popup appears because you've got the cursor over it.