# The tag popover is not working in the post body, is this by design or a bug?

Tags: support, tags, design

The popover showing the tag excerpt when hovering a inline tag, i.e. `[meta-tag:tags]` and `[tag:tags]` works on edit mode, but not on view mode.

With meta-tag prefix: [tags](/questions/tagged/tags),
With tag prefix: [tags](/questions/tagged/tags)

When hovering in edit mode, this is how the popover looks:

[image]

When hovering in view mode, this is what is being shown (it looks that is working as a standard link showing the title attribute):

[image]

Tested using Chrome for Mac, signed in and in incognito mode. Also tested in Safari, as an anonymous user.

There is a very old post from 2011, [Hovering over a tag no longer shows the tag popup on the edit/ask a question page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102815/289691), that was answered "status by design", but also there is a newer report from 2018 reporting exactly the same that have not being answered yet and is still open, [Hovering over a tag no longer shows the tag popup on the edit/ask a question page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102815/289691).

As November 2, 2022, what is the official stand about the tag pop-over on inline tags?

Related

- [Popover bug in Edit Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278816/289691) from 2016

Comment: I don't think this has worked for a long time. At least, there's a much older report for exactly the same thing: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319549/tag-popup-for-tag-markdown-no-longer-working-in-posts

Comment: Well, only four years. By now there are bugs that celebrated 10 years, and still fresh as new.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @animuson. I think that I have see it working recently (few months ago, maybe the last year)

Comment: Seems it's explicitly disabled for tags in the body of a post: `if ($tag.closest('.mixed-site-content, .js-post-body, .js-tag-preferences-container').length) return null; // not for mixed-mode channels content, post bodies or sidebar`  from https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=1f145d11a2e9 In which case the bug is that the preview shows the popover, rather than an actual post not showing it.

Comment: @animuson I edited the question... not sure if this make the question good for being reopened but at least might work as a request to add an update on the duplicate target.

Comment: This is still a duplicate reporting the exact same issue, whether it's a bug or not.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard That is perfectly fine... Do you have a suggestion about how to get an update about the issue ?

Comment: @Rubén sadly I have no suggestion, my experience with old non-critical bugs/requests isn't good, the vast majority get no attention at all, and these days only bugs/requests marked as [tag:status-review] even have a chance to get such attention. So on second thought, I have a suggestion, ask a mod to mark the dupe target as [tag:status-review], so that is has chance to get response. For that, think the best way with minimum noise is to custom flag the question, asking to add the tag, explaining why you think it's important enough.

Comment: Oh wait, the OP is a mod, so it can be much more simple.